# how to connect and use built in Identity from Angular login page?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular8, asp.net-core-3.1

I have installed a theme on asp.net core project and scaffolded identity for a faster development, which gives me a login controller named as `Login.cshtml.cs`. You can see the code below.

Now I want to use the function in the `Login.cshtml.cs` and login. Is there any way to do this? because `login.cshtml.cs` does not have API end point, I think it's hard to get to it.

Angular login script

```
submit() {
        const controls = this.loginForm.controls;
        /** check form */
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            Object.keys(controls).forEach(controlName =>
                controls[controlName].markAsTouched()
            );
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;

        const authData = {
            username: controls.username.value,
            password: controls.password.value
        };


    }
```

Identity Login file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }


        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }



        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the scaffolded identity login post method from the angular client project , you need to [enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) on the API server.

To enable CORS on your API, edit the Startup.cs. In the `ConfigureServices` method add CORS and a default policy:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44305")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
});
```

In the `Configure` method tell the application to use the CorsPolicy on all requests.

```
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

   // ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Then you could call the url `'https://localhost:44355/Identity/Account/Login'` in your login post request in angular. You could refer to below link which introduce to you a complete sample to use asp.net core Identity authentication ,JWT token authorization in asp.net core web api:

https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

You could adapt its [source code](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth) to asp.net core 3.1 with 3.1 packages .

Comment: Which means I can make a controller and use the same method as Identity Login function? I added already code to enable CORS, but i get different errors this time.


 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/test2", ok: false, …}